# Redux: Is there any smart way to avoid the antipattern of importing store for helper files?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-android

I'm currently build a React Native application using Redux the state management and Firebase Cloud Messaging for my real time communication.

To use FCM in the background on Android [you are required](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/messaging/receiving-messages#2)-Handle-background-messages) to create file called `bgMessaging.js`.

```
// @flow
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

My problem is that I need to dispatch an action here. The only solution I found for this was to import my store and call `store.dispatch()`. I've been told this is an anti-pattern and considered bad practice. What else could I do that is not an anti-pattern?

**Edit:**
Mark Erikson himself was so kind and [gave his opinion on this topic](https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/1045327597431861248). Thanks Mark!

Comment: Example of redux usage outside of React components are sparse, because they are usually advanced use cases (like your own). I think it would be an anti-pattern in a react component but not outside in a pure JS code. Do you have sources about it being a bad practice?

Comment: afaik the anti-pattern is making the redux store a singleton, and that is mainly because it makes writing tests more complicated as it's harder to isolate a store instance for a particular test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also come into the same scenario when writing my application. My approach to my React Native App was to create React Components, but deal with a lot of my data fetching/handling outside of React Components - because I didn't know whether I'd be using React all of the time, but wanted to create re-usable modules for my other Type/JavaScript projects. For example I'd created a few helper files which dealt with various APIs, but when I integrated Redux into my project - I had the same issue. How do I dispatch without re-adding in your store (as I can see this can be considered Anti-Pattern).

Reading into a few articles, there's no real place to suggest that this approach is 'Anti Pattern'. A lot of the time, stores are imported within the React Context (which is doesn't need to be) - this is Anti Pattern. In your use case, I don't really see how that can be Anti Pattern, I certainly came to this conclusion when I was doing the same thing. In my view 'Common' parts of the app should be used by many other parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm seeing is that you need to provide a function which has a single arg, typed as `RemoteMessage` which returns a promise, and you need to provide that function to `registerHeadlessTask` (wrapped in another function for some reason..)

So what if your bgMessaging file looked like this..

```
// @flow
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default store => {
  return async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message
    store.dispatch();
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

and in your index you did..

```
import bgMessaging from './src/bgMessaging';

const store = redux.createStore();

const bgMessagingFn = bgMessaging(store);

// Current main application
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeFirebaseDemo', () => bootstrap);
// New task registration
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessagingFn);
```